# На странице изображено 2 поля ввода. В оба текстовые строки вводятся серия значений

Tags: javascript

На странице изображено 2 поля ввода. В оба текстовые строки вводятся серия значений, разделенных запятой (значение числовые). при нажатии на кнопку должно исполниться функция. Функция формирует 2 массивы и их объединяет без повторов. Исходный массива выводится на

экран абзаце.
html

```
<form name="test">
Серия значений 1:<br>
<input name="arr1"><br>
Серия значений 2:<br>
<input name="arr2"><br>
Результат:<br>
<input name="result"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Получить результат"> 
</form>
```

js

```
let arr1 = form.arr1.value.split(',');
let arr2 = form.arr2.value.split(',');
```

Answer (score -1):

Если правильно понимаю, можно, например, так:

```js
function getArray() {
  const form = document.querySelector('form');
  const arr1 = form.arr1.value.split(',');
  const arr2 = form.arr2.value.split(',');
  
  const union = [...new Set(arr1.concat(arr2))];
  form.result.value = union;
}
```

```html
<form name="test">
  Серия значений 1:<br>
  <input name="arr1"><br>
  Серия значений 2:<br>
  <input name="arr2"><br>
  Результат:<br>
  <input name="result"><br>
  <input type="button" value="Получить результат" onclick="getArray()"> 
</form>
```